# Why does the JPanel resize on repaint?

Tags: java, swing, resize, jpanel, repaint

I have got a problem with my code: When I run the application, the JPanel added to another JPanel is shown, but when the parent-panel repaints, the child-panel is resized to 10x10 or something like that.
Here's my code:

```
public class GUIv2 extends JPanel {
Vector<Section> sections = new Vector<>();
String backgroundImage = "";

public GUIv2(String bgImage) {
    backgroundImage = bgImage;
}

public void addSection(int id, int x, int y, int width, int height) throws RuntimeException {
    for(Section sec : sections) {
        if(sec.getId() == id) {
            throw new RuntimeException("The given ID is already registered.");
        }
    }
    sections.add(new Section(id));
    sections.lastElement().setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
    this.add(sections.lastElement());
    this.repaint();
}
public Section getSection(int id) {
    for(Section sec : sections) {
        if(sec.getId() == id) {
            return sec;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    try {
        g.drawImage(ImageIO.read(new File(backgroundImage)).getScaledInstance(getWidth(), getHeight(), 100), 0, 0, null);
    }
    catch(IOException e) {

    }
}
}
```

I hope somebody can help me with this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: *the JPanel added to another JPanel is shown,* - the default layout manager for a JPanel is the FlowLayout which respects the preferred size of any component added to it. You didn't set a preferred size of your painting panel so you only get the (10 x 10) square when layout is done. You need to set the preferred size. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html)  for a working demo. Start with the working demo code and then make modifications based on your requirements.

Answer (score 4):

Several big problems with that code:

1. You are calling `setBounds(...)` on a component that is being placed in a container (the JPanel) that does not use `null` layout. This means that the `setBounds(...)` may display as you desire initially, but not later, or it may not be followed at all.
2. That you're using `setBounds(...)` at all. Almost always (99% of the time) to let the the component's preferred size and the container's layout manager handle the component's sizing
3. You're reading in an image during a painting method, something that needlessly slows the perceived responsiveness of the GUI. Why continually re-read the image in? Instead read it in once on component creation, store the image in a variable, and instead simply paint the image in the painting method, here `paintComponent`.
4. You're not calling `super.paintComponent(g)` in your override method, preventing Swing from cleaning dirty pixels.
5. Ignoring IO exceptions and reading in images as files. Better to handle the exceptions -- at least be notified of them, and read in the images as class resources not as a file, as this way you can package everything in a JAR file, and your images will be accessable.

All suggest that you have not yet studied the appropriate relevant tutorials. You can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info)

Any time the GUI is re-sized, the layout managers re-layout the components, and all "bounds" that are set are ignored, leading to your components shrinking. There are better ways of controlling the sizes and placements of your components, ways that we cannot suggest without knowing and seeing what GUI you are trying to create.

Comment: *"ways that we cannot suggest without knowing and seeing what GUI you are trying to create."* Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. **While I'm here:** For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW - you missed *"6) Scaling the image in a paint method (an asynchronous method call) while not providing an image observer to notify when the scaling is complete."*